# How to resize an image with ffmpeg

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, ffmpeg

I have not used ffmpeg before, this is my first time. It is creating image thumbnails but the images are way too big so I just need to scale them down.
I have an argument that is creating a thumbnail here:

```
processInfo.FileName = "\"" +HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/ffmpeg.exe") + "\"";
processInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-ss {0} -i {1} -f image2 -vframes 1 -y {2}", 5, "\"" + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(file) + "\"", "\"" + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(newfilename) + "\"");
```

So my question is, where inside of the argument can I specify the output image size?

Comment: Just after `-f image2`, you can insert `-s WxH` e.g. `-s 320x270`

Comment: @Mulvya that worked!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling%20(resizing)%20with%20ffmpeg), you only need to supply `-vf` option with your desired values, e.g. `-vf scale=320:240`